# simplexlsxgen saving file as xlsxxlsx

Tags: php

I found out about SimpleXLSXGen while trying to save an sql procedure to xlsx, after 3 months in deploy, it started duplicating the extension xlsx while saving my files.

They are now something as “activosfijosTue,30 Mar 021.xlsxxlsx”, making them unreadable until I change it back to xlsx, could you help me with that?

my code is as follows

```
session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Chihuahua");
    include_once('db.php');
    include_once('Conexion1.php');
    require('SimpleXLSXGen.php');
    
    //stored procedure

        $titulos = array('nombre_producto'=> 'Marca', 'modelo'=>  'Modelo', 'codigo_producto'=>  'Serie', 'inventario'=> 'Inventario', 'Descripcion'=> 'Caseta', 'carril'=> 'Carril', 'resguardante'=> 'Resguardante', 'nombre_categoria'=> 'Descripcion', 'estado'=> 'Estatus');
        $prueba = array_merge($titulos);
        $final= array_merge($prueba, $valores);
        
        $arquivo = 'activosfijos'.gmdate("D,d M Y").'xlsx';

    $xlsx = SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray( $final );
    $xlsx->downloadAs($arquivo);
```

Comment: Things don't suddenly just start happening. What changed when this problem started? Look there for your fix.

Comment: I haven't modify that code in last 2 weeks, was working with another document, and today i was showing it to my boss, when I found out the problem, will continue checking as you suggest